# File Being Processed More than Once in a Windows Batch File For... Loop. Why?

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a simple batch script to loop through files in a specific directory and prepend some text (client name) to the file name. The script works fine; however, the most recently modified file in the directory seems to be modified twice. I tried two approaches to the issue - using pushd for the directory and listing the full path in the for loop (code for each below).

Both approaches I end up with something like the following (assume the third file is the most recently modified file):

Original File Names:

```
SomeFile1.rtf  
SomeFile2.rtf  
SomeFile3.rtf
```

Renamed File Names:

```
TextToPrepend_SomeFile1.rtf  
TextToPrepend_SomeFile1.rtf  
TextToPrepend_TextToPrepend_SomeFile1.rtf
```

No, that's not a typo on the third file. It gets processed a second time and the TextToPrepend is  prepended a second time. I am fairly new to Windows Batch scripting and I have tried researching this issue, but cannot find a reason why it is doing this.  Any Help is appreciated.

Code:

```
pushd C:\Images\Data\

rem setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%X in (*.rtf) do (  
   ren "%%X" TEXTTOPREPEND_"%%X"  
)

popd
```

-- and --

```
rem setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%X in (C:\Images\Data\\*.rtf) do (  
   ren "%%X" TEXTTOPREPEND_"%%~nX".rtf  
)
```

If it helps any, the batch script is being executed on a Windows Server 2008 box.

Comment: I can't reproduce this from Windows 7.  I used for %x in (*.rtf) do ren %x AppendText_%x without the "double rename" occurring.

Comment: I did manage to reproduce it.  See ikegami's answer.

Comment: I **can** reproduce on win7 with this: `echo a > 00.rtf ; echo a > 01.rtf ; for %%i in (*.rtf) do (ren %%i a_%%i)`. 00.rtf gets renamed twice.

Comment: Adding text to the front is "prepending". "Appending" means adding to the end.

Comment: Prepending is what I am trying to do...I said that in the first of the question but went off with append for the rest...apologies.

Answer (score 4):

You apparently falsely assume the glob is expanded before the loop starts. I know it didn't in DOS. Solution:

```
for %%X in (*.rtf) do (
   ren "%%X" "TEXTTOAPPEND_%%~nX._rtf"
)
ren *._rtf *.rtf
```

or

```
md tmp
for %%X in (*.rtf) do (
   move "%%X" "TEXTTOAPPEND_%%~nX.rtf"
)
move tmp\* .
rd tmp
```

Not on my Windows box at the moment, so can't test to see I can replicate your behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I tried ikegami's solution and I am still getting the double rename. I added a new file to the directory and now it is doing the double rename on that file. It seems to be the most recently modified file. I have echos added to see where it is taking place and the file which is being double renamed is always processed second to last in the loop.

Comment: @Erik, oops! `foo.rtf_` is also known as `foo~1.rtf`, so `foo.rtf_` matches `*.rtf`. I've adjusted my solution.

Comment: Your new method works and I thank you greatly for your assistance. To add one additional question, since I am now renaming the files, my popd command does not work. I am assuming because the time it takes to rename to files. I have echo on and I see where it goes back to the main directory, but after the renaming finishes, it "pushes" back to the directory I listed in the pushd command. This script will process and rename, on average, about 2,000 files daily. Is there a way to halt the script while the renaming is executing?

Comment: @Erik, Nothing there should affect `pushd`. Ctrl-C will half the script.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do the trick with less code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /b *.rtf') do ren "%%X" TEXTTOPREPEND_"%%X"
```

Comment: +1, It is safe, as the output is cached completly before the execution of the ren ... even begins